# Converting a string into an array in Typescript?

Tags: string, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 4 and a Spring service that I throws an exception with the message being the toString of a List of messages. The problem is that when I receive the exception response and extract the message, instead of being treated like an Array of strings, it's treated as a single string in the format of: `"[message 1, message 2]"`

Is there a way in typescript to easily convert this String into an array of strings? I tried instantiating a new Array with the string like: `new Array(errorResponse.error.message);` but that didn't really work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: `message.substring(1, message.length()-1).split(",");` should give array of strings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should working for you:

```
var messages = message.substring(1, message.length-1).split(", ");
```

Fiddle with a function, which doing this is available [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20message%20%3D%20%22%5Bmessage%201%2C%20message%202%2C%20message%203%5D%22%3B%0D%0Afunction%20splitmessages(x)%20%7B%0D%0A%09var%20messages%20%3D%20x.substring(1%2C%20x.length-1).split(%22%2C%20%22)%3B%0D%0A%09return%20messages%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adocument.body.innerHTML%20%3D%20splitmessages(message)%5B0%5D%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20splitmessages(message)%5B1%5D%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20splitmessages(message)%5B2%5D%3B).

Answer (score 0):

It works with JSON.Parse("[message 1, message 2]");